# PHP regards to Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP. My Problem is as follows:

I am executing a mysql query that is using a variable `i`. Default value of `i` is set to 0. I want when I click on next button (type=submit):

```
if(isset($_POST['next'])){
    $arr = array(1,2,3);
    $i=array_rand($arr);
    echo $i;
}
```

value of `i` get updated in mysql query. The mysql query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE Id='".$i."'";
```

the program is working fine but value of i still remains the same i.e. default value. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: Have you got your update code?

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD You're misunderstanding the OP's use of the word 'update'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_rand()` directly in your query

**eg**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM exam WHERE Id='".array_rand($arr)."'";
```

Comment: Sir, you are right. But it does not match my code requirement. As i am using value of i to extract question and answer.so, when i click on submit type button, page refreshed and also the extracted values. So, i want to change the value of i only when i want instead through page refreshing.